# How to create new columns whose names are specified in a character vector

Tags: r

```
price <- c(
1.5,
4)

flavor <- c(
"Plain",
"Choc")

df <- data.frame(price,  flavor)
df_s  <- Matrix::sparse.model.matrix(~ . - 1, data = df)
toAdd <- c("flavorStraw", "flavorBlue")
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

df_s with two additional columns ("flavorStraw" and "flavorBlue"), whose values are . (the null values in sparse matrix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just need assignment to 0.  A single value can recycle to fill the rows

```
df[toAdd] <- 0
```

-output

```
df
  price flavor size form
1   1.5  Plain    0    0
2   4.0   Choc    0    0
```

#### Update

Based on the update i.e. `sparseMatrix`, one option is `cbind`

```
df_s <- cbind(df_s, matrix(0, ncol = length(toAdd), 
     nrow = nrow(df_s), dimnames = list(NULL, toAdd)))
df_s
2 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
  price flavorChoc flavorPlain size form
1   1.5          .           1    .    .
2   4.0          1           .    .    .
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have been more clear to specify that df is a sparse matrix. I edited my question. I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work for a sparse matrix. Any thoughts?